# C# acessing a class item from a static class

Tags: c#

I want to create a static class that contains all "Name" entries from the previous Client class:

```
    public class Client
    {
        [Key]
        public int ClientID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
static class ClientList
{
     public static string Name = Client.Name
}
```

I know this is not correctly, which would be the best way to call the Name items?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A Static class doesn't know anything about instance classes unless you pass to it some list of instances to work on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In static class, class objects have to be static. So create a static  object and use it's instance.

```
    public class Client
    {
        [Key]
        public int ClientID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    static class ClientList
    {
        static Client client = new Client();
        public static string Name = client.Name;
    }
```

with this way you can reach other members:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's good for control member in static class. But you  can only Client class for all actions.

```
public static class ClientList
{
      public static IDictionary<int, Client> Clients;

      static ClientList()
      {
          Clients = new Dictionary<int, Client>();    
      }

      public static void AddClient(Client client)
      {
           Clients.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, Client>(client.ClientID, client));
      }

      public static Client GetClient(int key)
      {   if (!Clients.ContainsKey(key)) throw new Exception("Client key is not valid");
        return Clients[key];
      }
      public static string GetClientName(int key)
      {
          return GetClient(key).Name;
      }

}
```

Use

```
var client1 = new Client();
client1.ClientID = 1;
client1.Name = "Client 1";
ClientList.AddClient(client1);

var client2 = new Client();
client2.ClientID = 2;
client2.Name = "Client 2";
ClientList.AddClient(client2);

var name = ClientList.GetClientName(client1.ClientID);
```